# CSS reset all styles in a div but allow lower styles to over write it

Tags: css

So have my main style sheet that sets all the styles for my site. But I have a div that opens as menu. I need it to have it's own style and I can't have it or it's decedents inherent any styles from the main style sheet. But after I reset the style I'm then styling the div like it's a whole new element. I found the all: initial; rest the elements. and #we_gallery_edit_window > * sort of works. But when I try to declare the new styles some of the new styles won't take because of precedence. here is my code so far:

```
h1
{
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#my_div > * /*Clear all previous CSS for #mydiv only */
{
    all: initial;
}
.my_div_child h1
{
   color: #F0F0F0;
}

<h1>Hello</h1>  //Should be black with background
<div id='my_div'>
    <h1 class='my_div_child'>Good bye</h1>  //Should be grey without background
</div>
<h1>Hello</h1> //Should be black with background
```

I need a selector that will override everything above it but has no precedence over anything below it. So remove the style set by h1 in the main div, then reset h1 of .my_div_child. it's not just the h1 element I'm having trouble with but that's the easiest example I can think of.

Comment: Can you post the HTML of your menu?

Comment: unfortunately no. most of the menu is generated by PHP and it is a very long code. I'll add a demo html.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after seeing the updated post, I think I get the idea.

I think you may be simply using the wrong selectors. You may [review CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) if you're unsure.

For one thing, if you want to style an `h1` with the class of `my_div_child`, the rule would be `h1.my_div_child`, or simply `.my_div_child`, if you don't have other, non-h1 elements with that class name. Using `.my_div_child h1` will select `h1` tags inside a parent container with the class of `my_div_child`, which is not what your HTML shows.

If you want to reset the styles of children of `#my_div`, you can use the `all: initial` selector with the wildcard like you did, but instead of using the direct child selector (>), just nest the wildcard regularly:

```
#my_div * {
  all: initial;
}
```

If you use the direct child selector, only the first level of children in `#my_div` will be reset, but grandchildren of `#my_div` won't be, which is probably not what you want.

Those things cleared up, simply use the above statement to reset your styles and then start styling the contents of `#my_div` as needed, and it should work because various tags (e.g., h1) will be more specific than the wildcard. See code snippet below.

That said, you may find it easier to simply override certain styles that aren't what you want by using specificity than to reset *everything* in `#my_div` and start over. Odds are there are some styles the menu will share with the site overall. For example:

```
h1 {
  font-style: italic;
}
#my_div h1 {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

If these approaches don't work, and you're still having trouble with your styles not working, you'd have to post some more specific code so we can work out what the problem is.

Example reset:

```css
html {
  background-color: coral;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  background-color: white;
}
#my_div * {
  all: initial;
}
#my_div .my_div_child {
  color: darkgray;
  font-size: 4em;
  /* note that font-style and font-family don't need rules b/c they have been reset by all: initial above */
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>  <!-- Should be black with background -->
<div id="my_div">
    <h1 class="my_div_child">Good bye</h1>  <!-- Should be grey without background -->
</div>
<h1>Hello</h1> <!-- Should be black with background -->
```